# Installing QGIS on Centos 7?

Tags: qgis, centos

I tried by following the instructions described [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) but they don't work. It looks like the repository mentioned in those instructions is actually not working:

> http://fedora.vitu.ch/QGIS/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14]
>   HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

I was unable to find any other working method. This other repo I was able to find only goes up to CentOS 6: http://elgis.argeo.org/

Comment: The most recent centos installers are at: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#rhel-centos-scientific-linux

Comment: @JohnBarça, that link leads to that "http://elgis.argeo.org" which I mentioned already and that is available up to CentOS 6 only so far. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Build from source then, it's not hard :D

Comment: Unfortunately it is. I spent half a day building dependencies and all the like and I still can't make it.
It is very frustrating to require to use a proprietary operating system to run an open source GIS because there aren't proper packages for it. :)

Comment: Have you ever managed to do this?

Comment: I finally managed to painfully build it from source, wasting almost a full day of my life in downloading and building all the darn components required and through an anally painful trial and error approach.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to successfully install QGIS with Python Plugin support on a CentOS 7 minimal install:

1. Install CentOS 7 minimal
2. Install a GUI Desktop

   yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"
3. Install QGIS+Python Support and supporting packages

   yum install qgis qgis-python python-devel PyQt4-webkit proj-devel geos-devel sqlite-devel gcc
4. Python Requirement: Python 2.7 comes standard in CentOS 7
5. Install pip

   wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

   python get-pip.py
6. Install pyspatialite (including /usr/include libraries)

   CFLAGS=-I/usr/include pip install pyspatialite

Answer (score 1):

try to find qgis rpms in rpmfind.net and install them manually

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=qgis