# Install QGIS 3.4.5 LTR on CentOS 7

Tags: qgis, installation

I have already read [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121290/installing-qgis-on-centos-7/221602#221602) but, I am still getting problems with my QGIS installation, and always show error with libgeos-3.4.2.so. I think, is because the default GEOS version installed by `yum install osgeo` is `3.5.0-1.rhel7.1`.

How can I install Install QGIS 3.4.5 LTR on CentOS 7 by using RPM or anything else?

pd: If I try `yum install qgis` is installed by default `2.14.9-1.el7`

Comment: Paul - the only thing I might bring up is CentOS is largely used as a server OS, even if you have the desktop environment set up, and thus I would wonder why you would want to install/use QGIS desktop on this machine?

Comment: I use CentOS 7.4 on a desktop because my (headless) production web server (http://ingeosur.co) is CentOS, so I don't need to learn a different way of doing things. Works fine for me, so.. I can check all my scripts in my desktop computer before to upload into server. But I'm also a geologist, so I need to use the same computer for my scientific work, and I've always needed to use Qgis. I see the operating system CENTOS works perfectly for me ,. Why do you find it strange?

Comment: Our use of CentOS is the bare server OS install. Everything we need to interact with the server we can do from our Windows or Linux machines (qgis, dbeaver, libreoffice, etc.). If we need to test something, we set up DEV, QA, as well as Prod CentOS servers. So when you say 'it works fine for me', installing QGIS on there may be where you reach the limit of what that means...

Comment: You are right!,  except Qgis.

Comment: Any luck on getting this to work?