# How to install QGIS-SERVER 3.6.X in Linux CenOS7

Tags: qgis

I do as QGIS official document with **yum** ,but got **Qgis-Serve** version **2.14** ，I need to install a higher release version.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Three choices:

1. you need to compile everything e.g dependencies like Qt, GDAL, Proj, Geos then QGIS
2. you need to use another distribution.
3. you need to "cheat" running QGIS Server from a Docker container to avoid two previous options and avoid pain for compiling because most native packages dependencies on a CentOS 7 are too old to fit with recent QGIS versions requirements.

The question is more or less similar to [Install QGIS 3.4.5 LTR on CentOS 7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314470/install-qgis-3-4-5-ltr-on-centos-7)

The approach by compiling I recommended is due to existing QGIS mailing list discussion at http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/qgis-3-on-CentOS-td5373151.html